# Responsive content background not streaching vertically

Tags: css, responsive-design

The website I am making is here: diyhelp.es

If you re-size the browser you will see the white background behind the content actually get smaller (even though the div gets larger) I've looked in the CSS and cannot see a problem. Since I don't know what is causing it I cannot paste any code (unless you want me to paste the full CSS?).

It's only a plain white background - no image.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I don't know what is causing it?

Comment: I edited my answer, to clarify the reason it happened. +1 would be nice ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `css.css` find line:438, that looks like this:

```
section.content, aside.sidebar, .footer-col { float: none; width: 100%; }
```

remove the `float:none;` and it should solve your problem. Why? I'm not sure totally, but `float:none;` [is known](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?p=5216746&postcount=3) to **mess up other floating divs**. It is better not to use it. I can't even think of a reason why you might need it. In you markup, you don't need it there, because when floating div is set to `width:100%` there is no room for anything to float beside it anyway.